# Disable Box Colider of game object in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-development

[disable box colider when player his the game object problem statement described in the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H1jo8.jpg)

Comment: Please state your question in text form rather than via a picture with handwriting

Answer (score 0):

So you want to disable the boxCollider of the childobjects of a parent GameObject ? when do you want the collision to be detected when hitting the parent or the childobject ? please do specify !!
an easy way to detect your collision is something colled `OnCollisionEnter(Collision)` for 3D or `OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D)` for 2D
I do recommand that you repost your question but you need to actually type the question.
Now to disable a collider your need to use enabled attribute `Collider.enabled = false;`